# gcloud crashed (OSError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/workspace/env/bin/python3.7'

Tags: python, deployment, build, python-3.7, gcloud

When trying to deploy my fastapi python service (on App Engine), I'm running into the following error in the deploy step:`ERROR: gcloud crashed (OSError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/workspace/env/bin/python3.7'`

I'm starting the deploy/build from my local machine with the following command: `gcloud builds submit --config config/cloudbuild/deploy.yaml --project $_PROJECT`.

Am I doing something wrong, or could it be something wrong with the gcloud builder? I've tried with both google cloud sdk version 274.0.1 and 300.0.0.

`deploy.yaml`:

```
steps:

  # Install gcc
  - name: 'python:3.7'
    id: 'install-dependencies'
    entrypoint: sh
    args:
      - -c
      - apt update && apt-get -y install gcc && python -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib

  # Run tests
  - name: 'python:3.7'
    id: 'test'
    env:
      - PYTHONPATH=lib
    entrypoint: python3
    args: ['-m', 'pytest']

  # Deploy
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['app', 'deploy', '--project', '$PROJECT_ID']

timeout: '1200s'
```

`app.yaml`:

```
runtime: python37
service: my-service
instance_class: F2

entrypoint: gunicorn main:app -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always

inbound_services:
- warmup

automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 1
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_instances: 2
  max_idle_instances: 1
```

Build output:

```
...
Finished Step #1 - "test"
Starting Step #2
Step #2: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Step #2:
Step #2:                    ***** NOTICE *****
Step #2:
Step #2: Official `cloud-sdk` images, including multiple tagged versions across multiple
Step #2: platforms, can be found at
Step #2: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker.
Step #2:
Step #2: Suggested alternative images include:
Step #2:
Step #2:     gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk
Step #2:     gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:alpine
Step #2:     gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:debian_component_based
Step #2:     gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:slim
Step #2:
Step #2: Please note that the `gcloud` entrypoint must be specified when using these
Step #2: images.
Step #2:
Step #2:                 ***** END OF NOTICE *****
Step #2:
Step #2: Services to deploy:
Step #2:
Step #2: descriptor:      [/workspace/app.yaml]
Step #2: source:          [/workspace]
Step #2: target project:  [my-project]
Step #2: target service:  [my-service]
Step #2: target version:  [20200710t134102]
Step #2: target url:      [https://my-service.uc.r.appspot.com]
Step #2:
Step #2:
Step #2: Do you want to continue (Y/n)?
Step #2: Beginning deployment of service [my-service]...
Step #2: Created .gcloudignore file. See `gcloud topic gcloudignore` for details.
Step #2: ERROR: gcloud crashed (OSError): [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/workspace/env/bin/python3.7'
Step #2:
Step #2: If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
Step #2:   gcloud feedback
Step #2:
Step #2: To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
Step #2:   gcloud info --run-diagnostics
Finished Step #2
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Build is essentially a pipeline of containers applied to a shared file system (`/workspace`).

The only state that's available to you is through `/workspace`.

Each step implicitly mounts `/workspace`.

Your step #0 is mostly redundant. It applies `apt` to the container image created in step #0 (and may as a side-effect) update the mounted `/workspace` too but these updates are discarded (except the mutations to `/workspace` when that step completes. You shouldn't try to update `/workspace` with e.g. Python module installs that you intend to use in subsequent steps.

I suspect you're installing `pytest` with the `requirements.txt` in step #0 but this doesn't correctly apply to step #1's use of `pytest`. What you should do is create a container that includes `pytest` so that you can run `pytest` in this step.

If you discard everything except step #2, it should work (it does for me).

If you wish to run `pytest` you'll need a container image that includes it so that you can run this isolated step before deployment.

Comment: Thanks, running `gcloud app deploy` directly works. I got it to work as well by removing `.gcloudignore` from and adding the virtual env dir. to `.gcloudignore`. Not sure why/how that could have been the issue, but..

Comment: hey @5ton3 if it solved your questions, please mark it as correct